# Cannot pattern match patterns ending with specific characters

Tags: python, regex, matching, python-re

I'm trying to match all patterns that end in bar.
This is my regex pattern `".*bar$"`.
I get no result... same thing happens if I use the carrot in to match at the beginning of patterns.

```
string = """
foo bar baz
bar foo baz
baz foo bar
bar baz foo
foo baz bar
baz bar foo
"""

search = re.findall(".*bar$", string)

for i in search:
    print(i)
```

Comment: "$" means it will match the end of the string only, string does not end in "bar" so that is the expected result

Comment: oh. What would you use to find each of the 3 patterns that end in bar?

Comment: I only see 2 lines that end in bar

Comment: sorry. match the two patterns ending in bar.

Comment: try `search = re.findall(".*bar\n", string)`

Comment: ok. that worked. thanks. what about if you have a single string like "danibarsambarbreadbar" and i want to match all the patterns ending in bar... how do you tell python to stop at bar without a linebreak.

Comment: @bananatoast you can set the `*` to be non-greedy, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern works if you set the `re.MULTILINE` flag. That way your pattern is matched on a line-by-line basis, so the `$` matches line endings in addition to the ending of the string as a whole.

```py
# Result: ['baz foo bar', 'foo baz bar']
search = re.findall(".*bar$", string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

**Edit:** Looks like you just want everything that ends in `bar`, regardless of line endings. In that case, you can tell set the star `*` to be non-greedy by adding a `?`:

```py
>>> re.findall(".*?bar", "danibarsambarbreadbar")
['danibar', 'sambar', 'breadbar']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import re
a ="foo bar baz\nbar foo baz\nbaz foo bar\nbar baz foo\nfoo baz bar\nbaz bar foo"
search = re.finditer("(.+bar)\n", a)
for i in search:
    print(i.group())
```

Output:

```
baz foo bar

foo baz bar
```

Or you can try This:

```
import re
a ="foo bar baz\nbar foo baz\nbaz foo bar\nbar baz foo\nfoo baz bar\nbaz bar foo"
search = re.findall("(.+bar)\n", a)
print(search)
```

Output:

```
['baz foo bar', 'foo baz bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = """
foo bar baz
bar foo baz
baz foo bar
bar baz foo
foo baz bar
baz bar foo
"""
re.findall(r"(.+bar)\n", string)
```

output:

```
['baz foo bar', 'foo baz bar']
```